# Declaring a var?

Tags: c++

What type is `it`? It says I need to declare it.

Recording Array is: `std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> > recordingArray;`

```
string line = "";
auto it = recordingArray.begin();

while(it != recordingArray.end())
{
  line.append(*it);
  line.append(',');
}
```

Also, it's not auto type.

Comment: Are you using C++11? If so, then `it` is an iterator to a vector of pairs. If not, then you need to get a new compiler.

Comment: In this case `it` is a `std::vector<>::iterator`

Comment: std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> >::iterator

Answer (score 6):

The type is `std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> >::iterator`, which the compiler should be able to figure out. If this doesn't work with `auto`, you need to enable C++11 support in your compiler, for example with `-std=c++0x` in g++ and clang. (The meaning of `auto` changed from C++03 to C++11).

Comment: I don't know about g++, but current versions of clang recognize `-std=c++11` as well. Since that's its actual name, you might want to start getting into the habit of using that flag instead.

Comment: @KevinBallard, any version of G++ or Clang++ with some C++11 support will recognise `-std=c++0x` but only the newest couple of releases recognise `-std=c++11`, so until e.g. G++ 4.6 is no longer widely used it's more portable to use `-std=c++0x`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Sure, but conversely, the versions of GCC and Clang that don't understand `-std=c++11` have much worse support for C++11 than the newer versions. So if you're going to continue using `-std=c++0x`, then you need to be careful that you're not making assumptions about the C++11 support that G++ 4.6 can't satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

it will be a `std::vector<*TheTypeInArray*>::iterator`. So you can either declare it as that or enable c++11 support so you can use `auto`.

Comment: Thanks, but then I get the error: no matching function for call to 'QString::append(std::allocator<std::pair<int, QString> >::value_type&)'

Comment: That's with the line:   line.append(*it);

Comment: @user1013512 that is because you are trying to append an `std::pair<int, QString>` to an `std::string`. That cannot work.

Comment: Thats because you are trying to append type pair<int, Qstring> to a std::string. you may need to do this: line.append((*it).second) assuming QString is compatible with std::string.